# Having trouble rendering my collection object in backbone marionette with coffeescript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I can't get ItemView to render my values defined in the testMap. All I want is the 1, 2, 3 to be dynamically inserted in the `<ol class='test-list'>` tag as `<li>` so my html would look like

```
<ol class="test-list">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ol>
```

What am I missing?

```
testMap = 
  a: '1'
  b: '2'
  c: '3'

class TestLayout extends Layout
  template: require '/test_template'
  regions:
    body: 'section'
  events:
    'click #testme': 'test'
  test: -> app.vent.trigger 'test'

class TestItemView extends ItemView
  template: require '/test-item'
  serializeData: -> {testMap}

class TestListView extends CollectionView
  tagName: 'ol'
  className: 'test-list'
  itemView: TestItemView

module.exports = class TestPlugin extends Application
  testList: null
  initialize: =>
    @test = new Collection
    app.vent.on 'test', @showTest, @
  showTest: ->
    app.layout.test.show @layout = new TestLayout
    @layout.body.show @testList= new TestListView collection: @test
```

My Html file named test-item looks like this:

```
<span class='test'>
  <%= @testMap %>
</span>
```

All my globals are defined in the extended files.

I think the culprit here is that I can't get my collection to bind to my itemView. Therefore, when I call `@showTest` function I get nothing because my testMap object is not talking to my `@test` variable. How can I marry the two object?

```
@layout.body.show @listView = new TestListView collection: @test
```

Comment: The collection you pass to your CollectionView is @test, but it's an empty one. Maybe in your module you should do `@test = new Collection testMap`. Also, why are you serializing testMap in your ItemView?

Comment: thanks so much for your response..yes i should have passed in my testMap object in my `@test` definition. However, where else should I be serializing the testMap? That's where I am calling my template to insert the values in the DOM

Comment: You should define testMap as an array of object, so when you create your @test collection it will contain 3 models. CollectionView then will pass every model to a dedicated itemView.

Comment: thank you..creating array object did it.